# 'String" is not convertible to '[(String)]'

Tags: string, swift

I am trying to split a string returned from a URL by ", " but when I attempt

```
var tagArray = [String]()
if response.responseObject != nil {
                let data = response.responseObject as NSData
                let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                self.tagArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString(", ") as String
                println("response: \(self.tagArray)") //prints the HTML of the page
            }
```

The line `self.tagArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString(", ") as String` throws the error "'String" is not convertible to '[(String)]'"

Anyone know how to properly split the string into the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is missing the `[]` in the cast -- you're casting to a `String` when you need to be casting to an *array* of `Strings`:

```
var tagArray = [String]()
if response.responseObject != nil {
    let data = response.responseObject as NSData
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    self.tagArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString(", ") as [String]
    println("response: \(self.tagArray)") //prints the HTML of the page
}
```